# How to download and process 2 sets of data, one after the other?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am making a webservice call to get a list of data. After I have all of that data I would like to make a web call for every item on that list. Here is the code I have this far:

```
let zipcde:String = self.zipCode
  let username:String = "tr1gger"
  //webservice call
  var listZip = [String]()
  let wsUrl: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://api.url.org/findNearbyTheseCodesJSON?postalcode=" + zipcde + "&maxRows=100&country=US&radius=25&username=" + username)!

  let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(wsUrl, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    //will happen when task is complete

    if let urlContent = data {
      let jsonObject = JSON(data: urlContent)

      if let jsonDict:JSON = jsonObject["postalCodes"]{
        let postalCode = "postalCode"
        for var i:Int = 0; i < jsonDict.count; i++ {
          print("Property: \"\(jsonDict[i][postalCode])\"")
          listZip.append(String(jsonDict[i][postalCode]))
        }


        self.showLoadingMessage()
        self.listOfZips = listZip
        self.getStores()

      }
    }

  })
  task.resume()
```

the self.getStores is a function that begins a for loop and calls a webservice for every item on the first list:

```
func getStores(){

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {

  for areaCode in self.listOfZips{

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://myUrl.thisPlace.net/getStores.php?zipcode=" + areaCode + "&ammoType=" + self.aType)!

    let task2 = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data2, response2, error2) -> Void in

      if let jsonObject2: NSArray = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data2!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)) as? NSArray{
        var storeName = [String]()
        var storeAddress = [String]()
        var storeId = [String]()
        var ammoStId = [String]()
        var ammoStock = [String]()
        var ammoPrice = [String]()

        for obj in jsonObject2{
          if let name: String = obj["storeName"] as? String{
            storeName.append(name)
            storeAddress.append((obj["storeAddress"] as? String)!)
            storeId.append((obj["storeId"]as? String)!)
          }
          else if let id: String = obj["storeId"] as? String{
            ammoStId.append(id)
            ammoStock.append((obj["ammoStock"] as? String)!)
            if let priceTemp: String = obj["ammoPrice"] as? String{
              ammoPrice.append(priceTemp)
            }
          }
        }
        var storeList = [StoreItem]()
        for var index:Int = 0; index < storeId.count; ++index{
          let sId = storeId[index]
          for var i:Int = 0; i < ammoStId.count; ++i{
            let aId = ammoStId[i]
            if sId == aId{
              //creating object
              let storeItem:StoreItem = StoreItem()
              storeItem.setAddress(storeAddress[index])
              storeItem.setName(storeName[index])
              storeItem.setId(Int(storeId[index])!)
              storeItem.setAmmoStock(Int(ammoStock[i])!)
              storeItem.setAmmoPrice(ammoPrice[i])
              storeList.append(storeItem)
            }
          }
        }
        self.storeListFinal.appendContentsOf(storeList)
      }

      self.myAlert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
      self.tableView.reloadData()

    })

    task2.resume()
  }
})
```

As you can see I am populating a table at the end of this call. This code takes about 18-20 seconds to finish. On my android version it takes like 2 seconds. How can I optimize this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use time profiler in instruments. Why not just download the whole set of data at once, store it in Core-Data and display it?

Comment: Do you want to reload your table everytime the task2 is completed? Another problem, you reload your table in background thread. Maybe it causes a delay (18-20s) to effect. Did you try to put it into main thread?

Comment: I want to reload the table only when it finishes that for loop. That is about how long it takes to "get" the data. I am looking it up now but how do you run on the main thread? Thanks!

Comment: @t4nhpt you were right that was causing the lag, I could take the loading message out now it's so fast haha. Leave an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoke UI update (reload table) in background thread can cause delay. So, you should move the UI update code to main thread:

```
let task2 = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data2, response2, error2) -> Void in

      ....

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
          self.myAlert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
          self.tableView.reloadData()
      })

    })
```

This way above can temporary solve your problem, but, it will reload you table many times because you create many tasks in loop. You should think another way to improve this.

Comment: I did move it outside the for loop. It now loads the data in 1 second. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> I am making a webservice call to get a list of data. After I have all of that data I would like to make a web call for every item on that list.

This sort of situation is *exactly* the subject of the WWDC 2015 video on Advanced NSOperations. By using an NSOperation to encapsulate each your network "tasks", you can create the dependencies you need (the web service call must complete successfully before anything else can happen) and queue up the other "tasks" (the web call for each item) so that they are all performed independently and in good order. You'll find that the logic of expressing this sort of ordered dependency is *much* easier to express if you use NSOperations in this way. Watch the video, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I will check this out later tonight, thanks for replying.

Comment: NSOperation is definitely the way to go. But depending on your use case you might not even need to add dependencies - just subclass `NSOperation`, override `main()`, call the first web service synchronously, and when it's done go through results synchronously, and exit when the last is completed.

Comment: @MathewS The web calls can be made simultaneously, so it makes more sense to queue them onto a nonserial operation queue and let the system have at it. But nothing at all can happen unless the initial download-and-parse succeeds. Hence my suggestion.

Comment: @matt thank you very much for letting me know about this video, it wasn't exactly what I needed to solve my problem but I will definitely try out this app structuring.

Answer (score 0):

You used shared `NSURLSession` and it seems to that session queued what you requested. The secondary queries are not executed in same time, I think this is the reason for slow performance.

You can change max concurrent connection count for each host by below code:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration* config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
config.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 20;
```

Above codes may have to be called before any shared `NSURLSession` is created. To make it sure, I suggest that you should create a custom NSURLSession that uses explicitly defined configuration.

ps. IMO, changing serve scripts so the sever can provide results with just 1 call is Best Solution if You can.

Comment: the second set of queries is depending on the result of the first. Thanks for your reply

Comment: also I think this is in C

Comment: I understood what your needs, my point is that the second set of queries have to executed in same time. To make it possible, you have to set `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` as appropriate value for `NSURLSession`'s configuration. Otherwise, the second set queries will be executed one by one.

Answer (score 0):

use, dispatch_sync with background thread.
You can find solution, in my post, there: [Swift Serial Dispatch Block only finish after delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440530/swift-serial-dispatch-block-only-finish-after-delegate/29442199#29442199)